# iPhone Application Memory Issue

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, instruments

I have created an iPhone Application where I have managed to handle leaks using the Profiling tool of XCode.

I have a gallery of images shown in `UIScrollview` when I load the `view.Images` in the gallery changes on each load of the view of iPhone.

I managed to remove the leaks using the profiler, but what happens now is memory gets increased by some amount on each load. I really cannot get why the memory increases on each load,when there are no leaks in the application.

Can anybody help me in finding this issue?

Comment: when you load something it goes into memory.. that's why it increases in memory.

Comment: When there are no actual leaks, take a look at the Allocations tool to track down likely suspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have leaks in the app it does not mean that your memory management logic is correct.:d

Do an analyze from tools menu.

And read again your code to see where you can release objects that are no longer needed.
In a gallery you should load only what users sees and the previous and next image only one step.

So if you are displaying one image on screen load only the next and the previous if you have one. So you will have only 2 or 3 images alive in memory.  When user scrolls load next and release the previous, you can cash more than one image like 2 3 4 depending on the size,